# How to avoid System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityCommandExecutionException in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

This is my code of the Index action in Notifications controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            //gets the current user
            ApplicationUser currentUser = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>().FindById(System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.GetUserId());

            //checks if the user is logged in
            bool val1 = (System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User != null) && System.Web.HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
            if (val1 == false)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");
            }
            var myNotif = db.Notifications.Where(s => s.User1_Id == currentUser.Id || s.User2_Id == currentUser.Id).Where(s => s.Active_Status != currentUser.Id);
            ViewBag.Autobots = new NotificationStatus[myNotif.Count()];
            int i = 0;
            foreach(var item in myNotif)
            {
                ViewBag.Autobots[i].name = db.Users.Where(x => item.Active_Status == x.Id).First().FirstName + " " + db.Users.Where(x => item.Active_Status == x.Id).First().LastName;
                i++;
            }
            return View(myNotif.ToList());
        }

        private class NotificationStatus
        {
            string name;
        }
```

I am getting this error here. So how do I avoid it? I am trying to send data to view, hence I am using array of strings. Is my Linq query wrong anywhere?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BrkRU.png)

Comment: Hello,Try to look at the inner exceptions.

Comment: In the image you attached there is a link copy exception detail to the clipboard. Click on it and then paste in a text editor

Answer (score 0):

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
   var userId=User.Identity.GetUserId();

   if(!User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)  return RedirectToAction("Login", "Account");

  var myNotif = db.Notifications
              .Where(s => s.User1_Id == userId || s.User2_Id == userId )
              .Where(s => s.Active_Status != userId).ToList();

  ViewBag.Autobots = new NotificationStatus[myNotif.Count()];
  int i = 0;
  foreach(var item in myNotif)
    {
       var user=db.Users.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id==item.Active_Status);
       ViewBag.Autobots[i].name = user.FirstName + " " + user.LastName;
        i++;
    }
   return View(myNotif.ToList());
}
```

I just refactor your code, with some minor changes.

this should work, at list will not give you that error.

My sugestion is to create a ViewModel, like:

```
public class ViewModel
{
 public List<Notification> Notifications {get;set;}
 public NotificationStatus[] NotificationStatusArr {get;set;}
}
```

and send the viewmodel to the view, not ViewBags!